# Prove that when writing up all even numbers in a column, then chaining $2n+1$ from them, we get all natural numbers exactly once.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, natural-numbers, infinite-matrices

**Here is the idea:** Write up all even numbers in the first column, then get numbers in the second column by taking the number to the left ($n$), and calculating $2n+1$. And keep repeating this.

Here is how it's done:
$$\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 15 & 31 & 63 & \dots \\
2 & 5 & 11 & 23 & 47 & 95 & 191 & \dots \\
4 & 9 & 19 & 39 & 79 & 159 & 319 & \dots \\
6 & 13 & 27 & 55 & 111 & 223 & 447 & \dots \\
8 & 17 & 35 & 71 & 143 & 287 & 575 & \dots \\
10 & 21 & 43 & 87 & 175 & 351 & 703 & \dots \\
12 & 25 & 51 & 103 & 207 & 415 & 831 & \dots \\
14 & 29 & 59 & 119 & 239 & 479 & 959 & \dots \\
16 & 33 & 67 & 135 & 271 & 543 & 1087 & \dots \\
18 & 37 & 75 & 151 & 303 & 607 & 1215 & \dots \\
20 & 41 & 83 & 167 & 335 & 671 & 1343 & \dots \\
22 & 45 & 91 & 183 & 367 & 735 & 1471 & \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{matrix}$$

And this is what it looks like to only write up the first $50$ numbers gotten this way:

$$\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 3 & 7 & 15 & 31 & \dots\\
2 & 5 & 11 & 23 & 47 & \dots & \\
4 & 9 & 19 & 39 & \dots & & & \\
6 & 13 & 27 & \dots & & & & \\
8 & 17 & 35 & \dots & & & & \\
10 & 21 & 43 & \dots & & & & \\
12 & 25 & \dots & & & & & \\
14 & 29 & \dots & & & & & \\
16 & 33 & \dots & & & & & \\
18 & 37 & \dots & & & & & \\
20 & 41 & \dots & & & & & \\
22 & 45 & \dots & & & & & \\
24 & 49 & \dots & & & & & \\
26 & \dots & & & & & & \\
28 & \dots & & & & & & \\
30 & \dots & & & & & & \\
32 & \dots & & & & & & \\
34 & \dots & & & & & & \\
36 & \dots & & & & & & \\
38 & \dots & & & & & & \\
40 & \dots & & & & & & \\
42 & \dots & & & & & & \\
44 & \dots & & & & & & \\
46 & \dots & & & & & & \\
48 & \dots & & & & & & \\
50 & \dots & & & & & & \\
\end{matrix}$$

**Question:** Do we get all natrual numbers exactly once when writing up all rows this way?

**Bonus question:** When writing up numbers in order, what curve do we approximate when connecting the end of each row? (What curve do we get closer and closer to by adding more numbers in order to our list?)

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image: Connecting the endpoint of each row]

My guess is that the red line approximates $\ln(x), x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Note $f(k)=2k+1$. You're asking the following question: if $f^n(a)=f^m(b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are even numbers, do we have $a=b$ and $n=m$? Well for instance $m\geqslant n$ and $f^{m-n}(b)=a$. Because $a$ is even, $m-n=0$ so $m=n$ and $a=b$.

Comment: What is being denoted by $f^n(a)$?

Comment: @MariaMazur Whoops, I'm fixing that.

Comment: $f^n(a)=f\circ f \circ \dots\circ f(a)$ where $f$ appears $n$ times

Comment: http://oeis.org/A075300 is worth a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the first column has all even numbers, i.e., those $\equiv 0 \bmod 2$, and not those $\equiv 1 \bmod 2$

the second column has the numbers $\equiv 1\bmod 4$, and the first two columns miss out the ones $\equiv 3 \bmod 4$

Likewise the first three columns miss out only the numbers $\equiv 7 \bmod 8$

Suppose we have the integer $n$ - which column does it appear in? Well if $2^r$ is the greatest power of $2$ which divides $n+1$, then your number will appear in the $(r+1)^{th}$ column.

I've sketched out some ideas from which you might see patterns to explore, and conjectures to prove. Incidentally, your table would be more suggestive if you took it up to $31$ or $63$ and counted the numbers in the different columns.

Comment: That's most likely the answer, thank you! Can you also figure out what curve we get in the Bonus question?

Comment: @DanielP I left you a hint as to how to tackle that one with the numbers $31$ and $63$.

Comment: And I figured it out! :) Columns from right to left will contain $1, 2, 4, 8,\dots$ elements. This means that we're approximating a $\log_2$ based function. And depending on how we parametrize it, it could literally be exactly $\log_2(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

First, observe that your the entry in the $m$-th row and $n$-column is given by: $m_{m,n}=(2m+1)2^n-1$ for $m,n\geq0$.

From this it is straightforward to show the mapping $(m,n)\to m_{m,n}$ is injective.

Regarding your second question:

$$
(2m+1)2^n-1\leq M\\
\Leftrightarrow n\leq\Big(\log(M+1)-\log(2m+1)\Big)/\log(2)
$$

Thus, the red line is given by

$$
n=\Big\lfloor \Big(\log(M+1)-\log(2m+1)\Big)/\log(2)\Big\rfloor
$$

So you were kinda right with you assumption!

Comment: We were also asked to prove the mapping is surjective by the exactly once.  It is also true.